# How to know what motor/ESC/propeller combination will work for a quadcopter?

Tags: quadcopter, brushless-motor, esc, multi-rotor

I am preparing for my first quadcopter build and need to know how to tell what motors/ESC's/propellers will work with each other. I also would like to know how to tell what the motors would be capable of carrying/how much thrust they have. I would like to put a camera on this copter. I cannot find anywhere a straight answer to this question.

The ones I currently think are the ones I want are:

ESC:
https://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__25365__Turnigy_Multistar_30_Amp_Multi_rotor_Brushless_ESC_2_4S.html

Motor: https://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__28112__Turnigy_D3530_14_1100KV_Brushless_Outrunner_Motor_US_Warehouse_.html

Propeller: 11inch

This copter needs to be able to carry a camera (~go pro)

TLDR: How does one match ESC's/Motors/Propellers, and how to tell if they can get the job done?

(ESC - Electronic Speed Control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step to decide electronics is roughly estimate your all up weight (AUW) which is total flying weight including payload. Now your target total maximum thrust(T) provided by system should be just double your AUW which will ensure good maneuverability and control. This will given you amount of thrust to be provided by each motor (in your case it will be T/4 as you are using 4 rotors).
Now you have got a criteria to choose a motor. 
For multirotor purpose, people generally use low rpm brushless motors (< 1200KV). You should also refer to [this](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2416/low-amp-fpv-quadcopter-motors/2440#2440) link for more criteria for motor selection. Once motor is selected, propeller can be selected based on manufacturer data for wattage and thrust for compatible propellers. 
ESC can be chosen which is rated higher than maximum current rating of motor.

In your case, motor looks good as maximum thrust is around 1Kg. However no propeller data is given. I would personally suggest you to bench test motor with range of propeller to find optimum performance. However user comments in discussion section on webiste suggest 10x4.5 prop. Current rating for motor is 22A so ESC you are considering (30) should do fine.